# Put vertical dashed line dynamically at the end of longest bar

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-python

I drew a horizontal bar chart like below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(x=prices, y=['Average ', 'Lowest ', 'Last ', 
                          'Proposed '], 
      orientation='h',
      color = ['Average ', 'Lowest ', 'Last ', 'Proposed '])

fig.show()
```

Now my aim is to put a vertical dashed line at the end of the longest bar, in this case the belowest(average) bar is the longest but it can be change in different runs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a vertical line, add `add_vline()`. Since the code doesn't match the data you presented, I created the code based on the [example](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/#horizontal-and-vertical-lines-and-rectangles) in the official reference. Even if you change to different conditions, the maximum value of the resulting data frame is used as the position of the vertical line. Please change the conditions and check it out.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
fig = px.bar(df, y='country', x='pop', text='pop')
fig.add_vline(x=df['pop'].max(), line_width=2, line_dash='dash', line_color='red')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is recommended to read the official reference. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to check it in my jupyter notebook, unfortunately it prints an error like that `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_vline'`
It is interesting to me that how the code worked in your machine but not in my machine

Comment: It is interesting  that I run codes from official site in my jupyter notebook it also doesn't work,  what can be the reason?

Comment: What is the version you have installed? I am. plotly 5.1.0. you need `pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.5"` to use it with notebook.